# Adding trace lines with plotly.graph_objects

Tags: plotly-python

Here is an image:

[image]

I want to plot three error graphs with predicted vs actual values in one plot, scatter plots. I couldn't figure out how to do that with `plotly.express`, but I figured it out with `graph_objects` library of `plotly`. But now I want to add a `traceline` for each individual data set, and annotations with the `r^2` value and the mean absolute error.

I found how to add `tracelines` in `plotly.expresss` but not in `plotly.graph_objects :sweat_smile`. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
    f3 = go.Figure(
        data = [
            go.Scatter(x=errors_doge_df['Day 1 percent test'], y=errors_doge_df['Day 1 percent predicted'],mode='markers', name="Day 2"),
            go.Scatter(x=errors_doge_df['Day 2 percent test'], y=errors_doge_df['Day 2 percent predicted'],mode='markers', name="Day 3"),
            go.Scatter(x=errors_doge_df['Day 3 percent test'], y=errors_doge_df['Day 3 percent predicted'],mode='markers', name="Day 4"),
    ],
        layout = {"xaxis": {"title": "Test Percentage Change Data"}, "yaxis": {"title": "Predicted Percentage Change Data"}, "title": "Doge Prediction Error Graph"}
)
    f3.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You were using `mode='markers'`, if you want to plot lines instead of points, use `mode='lines'` instead of `mode='markers'`. Or you could use `mode='lines+markers'` for both


[image: plot graph objects]